# Extract items from JSONArray containing ArrayList stored from TSV and assign it to String one by one

Tags: arrays, json, csv, arraylist, bufferedreader

I have a JSONArray named DataExtract containing objects like below extracted from a TSV file:
[image]

The requirement is to extract the items one by one like extract the value from records[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqpgQ.png)'s 0th element : agent_4 and assign to a String named ID, then records[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqpgQ.png)'s 1st element and assign it to text and same for records[2]'s 2nd element. And the final output should look like below :

DataExtract = {
ID : agent_4,
text = "Can i text you the information"
count = 1 ,

ID:  agent_11,
text = "",
count =2,

}
How can i achieve this ? or there is some other way to store the arraylist information and assign it one by one

Current code which is getting me as one single jsonArray :

```
List<List<String>> records = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(content))) {
            String line;
            //todo to check if it is required to be sent via Map or Json Object
            
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] values = line.split("\t");
                records.add(Arrays.asList(values));
            }
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String jsonArray = gson.toJson(records);
            logger.debug("Print value{}", jsonArray);
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("Data:", jsonArray);
            for(int i =0;i<jsonArray.size();i++) { //for jsonArray
              for(int j=0;j<i;j++) { //inner loop for each elements
               
               String candidateID=String.valueOf(jsonArray.get(j));
                    }  //but it is getting the entire string not separate elements like i want to extract agent_4 only in this string , the split is also not working
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked with JSONObject:

Load file by BufferedReader and use JsonArray to format your Json output

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.tsv"));

String[] fieldNames = reader.readLine().split("\t");


List<JSONObject> rows = new ArrayList<>();

// Read tsv file line by line
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    
    String[] fields = line.split("\t");

    JSONObject row = new JSONObject();
    for (int i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++) {
        row.put(fieldNames[i], fields[i]);
    }
    rows.add(row);
}

reader.close();

// Convert the list of rows to a JSON array
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(rows);
```